# How to get datarow column values by using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datarow

Iam using a datatable to fetch table values from mysql DB.

My codes

```
 public static DataTable mydealdetails()
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = "Server=localhost;database=mytable;uid=root;password=Mytable";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`.`mydealdetails`";
            MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            ma.Fill(DS);
            return DS.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And iam also using this methode

```
 var expression = "MovieMasterId = '"+mouvieid+"'";

   DataRow[] foundRows = allmydeals.Select(expression);
```

I can get two rows count here,but i want to know how can i get each column values by using this methode

Comment: Use a loop: `foreach(DataRow row in foundRows) Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", row.ItemArray))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Thank you so much...